# Backup using adb on a phone with a dead screen

Tags: backup, adb

I have a Galaxy S3, screen is visually and touch impaired. It is USB debug enabled, un-rooted.

I'm able to use [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/) to see my screen, which i'm able to unlock. I then run this command:

> adb backup –apk –shared –all –f /backup/mybackup.ab

Which then initiates a backup on the phone. On the screen I can see it asking for an encryption password, which i provide by keyevent through adb. The final sticking point, is being unable to find a keyevent which will press the "Backup up my data" button. I am able to tab to it, and have it highlighted, but the 'space' and 'enter' events do not trigger it, as well as 'soft_right'.

I'm getting my keyevents from [HERE](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.com/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html).

[image: ]![Backup Scr][2]

If there is another way for me to dump the ab, that would be awesome.

Comment: Am surprised that Droid@Screen does not have a mouse to interact with it such as remote vnc... :o what other key events have you tried? BTW, can you recall what hardware key sits underneath directly the input soft button labelled "Backup my data"? Maybe it needs *keycode_focus* first then *keycode_enter*?

Comment: There isn't a hardware key under that.

Answer (score 7):

I was in the same situation as you.
Once you enter the full backup screen
Use the following commands:

```
adb shell input text <your password>
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 23
```

the "adb shell input keyevent 22" command is Dpad Right, you'll be able to select back up my data
the "adb shell input keyevent 23" is the Dpad Center, It will allow you to select enter

22 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT"

23 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried sending a `KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER`?

```
adb shell input keyevent 23
```

Comment: That moves the focus off the target, but does not appear to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer) and the [Screencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) plugin to use your keyboard and mouse from your desktop computer to control the handset?

That would make life easier instead of fiddling around with using `adb shell input keyevent ...`

Comment: I'm not rooted, so screencast isn't going to work, correct?

Comment: I confirm you do not need to be rooted, however, it is pretty limited, but maybe that's because the handset used in conjunction with screencast, is eclair 2.1...