# Transfer sms data from a Samsung Gal. 3 with black screen of death

Tags: sms, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with the black screen of death. I was able to download files from phone and sd card onto my computer.

However, I would like to access my old sms text messages. I have "sms backup and restore" app on phone, but it hasn't backed up any recent messages. I also have Kies software on my computer, which I used to recover all media, contacts, etc., but it will not backup/restore messages for some reason.

How can I recover my sms text messages?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the device is running Android 4.0 or higher, you could use `adb backup` to get all data to your computer. Then you could extract your messages from the backup file, see e.g.:

- [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575)
- [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23357/16575)
- [Backup using adb on a phone with a dead screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/36224/16575)

If you have root access, an easier way might be to directly exctract the corresponding database using `adb pull`. While the SMS database usually is located in `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/mmssms.db`, it seems on Samsung devices different locations might be used. See e.g. [Where on the file system are SMS messages stored?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16915/16575)

A third variant would be utilizing VNC to substitute your screen: [Broken Screen + Using adb shell to run vnc server](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19317/16575).